# How to install uboot tools in centos 8

Tags: centos, boot, u-boot

I want use the command mkimage in my Centos 8.

I have attempted to install as root uboot-tools using the command dnf install uboot-tools but this is not available.

Could anyone guide me as to how I can install uboot-tools on my system please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to build u-boot tools from scratch, this will not take long:

```
wget https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/archive/v2020.07.tar.gz
tar zxf v2020.07.tar.gz
make  -C u-boot-2020.07 mrproper qemu-x86_64_defconfig tools
```

`mkimage` will be available here: `u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage`.

```
ls -gG u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage
-rwxrwxr-x 1 240152 Sep 22 08:13 u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage

u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage 
Error: Missing output filename
Usage: u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage -l image
          -l ==> list image header information
       u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage [-x] -A arch -O os -T type -C comp -a addr -e ep -n name -d data_file[:data_file...] image
          -A ==> set architecture to 'arch'
          -O ==> set operating system to 'os'
          -T ==> set image type to 'type'
          -C ==> set compression type 'comp'
          -a ==> set load address to 'addr' (hex)
          -e ==> set entry point to 'ep' (hex)
          -n ==> set image name to 'name'
          -d ==> use image data from 'datafile'
          -x ==> set XIP (execute in place)
       u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage [-D dtc_options] [-f fit-image.its|-f auto|-F] [-b <dtb> [-b <dtb>]] [-i <ramdisk.cpio.gz>] fit-image
           <dtb> file is used with -f auto, it may occur multiple times.
          -D => set all options for device tree compiler
          -f => input filename for FIT source
          -i => input filename for ramdisk file
Signing / verified boot not supported (CONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE undefined)
       u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage -V ==> print version information and exit
Use '-T list' to see a list of available image types
```

You can now move it, say, into `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo cp u-boot-2020.07/tools/mkimage /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Hi @Prasanna Kotrappa if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi, I tried but getting some error, [root@loke zip_fpga]# make  -C u-boot-2020.07 mrproper qemu-x86_64_defconfig tools
make: Entering directory '/mnt/asic_work/kotrappa/zip_fpga/u-boot-2020.07'
  CLEAN   spl/u-boot.cfg
  CLEAN   u-boot.cfg
  CLEAN   scripts/basic
  CLEAN   scripts/dtc/pylibfdt
  CLEAN   scripts/kconfig
  CLEAN   include/config include/generated spl
  CLEAN   .config .config.old include/autoconf.mk include/autoconf.mk.dep include/config.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c

Comment: HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  UPD     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
  CFG     spl/u-boot.cfg
  GEN     spl/include/autoconf.mk
  UPD     include/config/uboot.release
  UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  UPD     include/generated/dt.h
  CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h

Comment: CC      arch/x86/lib/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/pylibfdt/libfdt.i
  PYMOD   scripts/dtc/pylibfdt/_libfdt.so
unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
make[4]: *** [scripts/dtc/pylibfdt/Makefile:27: scripts/dtc/pylibfdt/_libfdt.so] Error 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:419: scripts/dtc/pylibfdt] Error 2
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:419: scripts/dtc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:577: scripts] Error 2

Comment: make: *** [Makefile:547: __build_one_by_one] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/mnt/asic_work/kotrappa/zip_fpga/u-boot-2020.07'

Comment: Do you have swig  installed on your system ? It is required for building u-boot.